# CompletableFuture#whenComplete not called if thenApply is used

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java-8, completable-future

I have the following code (resulting from [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40251528/how-to-use-executorservice-to-poll-until-a-result-arrives)) that schedules a task on a remote server, and then polls for completion using `ScheduledExecutorService#scheduleAtFixedRate`. Once the task is complete, it downloads the result.
I want to return a `Future` to the caller so they can decide when and how long to block, and give them the option to cancel the task.

My problem is that if the client cancels the `Future` returned by the `download` method, `whenComplete` block doesn't execute. If I remove `thenApply` it does. It's obvious I'm misunderstanding something about `Future` composition... What should I change?

```
public Future<Object> download(Something something) {
    String jobId = schedule(something);
    CompletableFuture<String> job = pollForCompletion(jobId);
    return job.thenApply(this::downloadResult);
}

private CompletableFuture<String> pollForCompletion(String jobId) {
    ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    CompletableFuture<String> completionFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();

    ScheduledFuture<?> checkFuture = executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {           
            if (pollRemoteServer(jobId).equals("COMPLETE")) {
                completionFuture.complete(jobId);
            }
    }, 0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    completionFuture                
            .whenComplete((result, thrown) -> {
                System.out.println("XXXXXXXXXXX"); //Never happens unless thenApply is removed
                checkFuture.cancel(true);
                executor.shutdown();
            });
    return completionFuture;
}
```

On the same note, if I do:

```
return completionFuture.whenComplete(...)
```

instead of

```
completionFuture.whenComplete(...);
return completionFuture;
```

`whenComplete` also never executes. This seems very counterintuitive to me. Shouldn't logically the `Future` returned by `whenComplete` be the one I should hold on to?

**EDIT:**

I changed my code to explicitly back-propagate the cancellation. It's abhorrent and unreadable, but it works and I couldn't find a better way:

```
public Future<Object> download(Something something) throws ChartDataGenException, Exception {
        String jobId = schedule(something);
        CompletableFuture<String> job = pollForCompletion(jobId);
        CompletableFuture<Object> resulting = job.thenApply(this::download);
        resulting.whenComplete((result, thrown) -> {
            if (resulting.isCancelled()) { //the check is not necessary, but communicates the intent better
                job.cancel(true);
            }
        });
        return resulting;
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

I've discovered [tascalate-concurrent](https://github.com/vsilaev/tascalate-concurrent#3-dependentpromise), a wonderful library providing a sane implementation of `CompletionStage`, with support for dependent promises (via the `DependentPromise` class) that can transparently back-propagate cancellations. Seems perfect for this use-case.

This should be enough:

```
DependentPromise
          .from(pollForCompletion(jobId))
          .thenApply(this::download, true); //true means the cancellation should back-propagate
```

Didn't test this approach, mind you.

Comment: It doesn't even enter the `whenComplete` block. I put a breakpoint and a `System.out.print` inside, and neither does the breakpoint get hit nor does the line get printed. Both happen if I remove the `thenApply` bit.

Comment: According to my understanding it should be the reverse of what you report. `completionFuture.whenComplete()` is a pure function and shouldn't change anything in the way `completionFuture` itself operates. If you don't return the result of `whenComplete`, it should become unreachable and subject to GC.

Comment: Absolutely agreed. But this is what I'm seeing... If return the result of `whenComplete`, and `cancel` it immediately, I don't get XXXXX in the console. On the other hand, if I  return the original `completionFuture` and `cancel` _that_, I do.

Comment: This is my new understanding: 1. it is correct to pass the stage before applying `whenComplete` because you must cancel _this_ stage to make it trigger the action in the downstream `whenComplete` stage. If you cancel the `whenComplete` stage, it simply doesn't execute. 2. You must also hold on to the `whenComplete` stage to ensure its reachability. Confusing...

Comment: I have tried to reproduce your problem based on your code (adding the missing parts), and I don't have your issue: `whenComplete()` is always executed (after the scheduled tasks completes the future), and cancelling by the client has absolutely no effect – cancellation is not backpropagated. Also, if I implement backpropagation of the cancellation, `whenComplete()` is still executed when the client cancels the future. Could you turn this code into an [mcve]?

Comment: @Didier L: I guess, the fact that cancellation is not backpropagated is exactly what the OP has to realize.

Comment: @Holger Probably the next step indeed, but that will not explain why `whenComplete` is not executed

Comment: @Holger Backpropagation is exactly what I misunderstood, as you say. I thought the entire pipeline is cancelled implicitly (sort of like closing the wrapper stream closes all underlying ones).

Comment: Actually you can draw a parallel to a stream, but keep in mind that the wrapper is "upstream" from the wrapped object. If you close the wrapped stream, it doesn't propagate to the wrapper, same as here.

Comment: For backpropagation, you can also test for `resulting.isCancelled()` instead of relying on `instanceof`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your structure is as follows:

```
           ┌──────────────────┐
           │ completionFuture |
           └──────────────────┘
             ↓              ↓
  ┌──────────────┐      ┌───────────┐
  │ whenComplete |      │ thenApply |
  └──────────────┘      └───────────┘
```

So when you cancel the `thenApply` future, the original `completionFuture` object remains unaffected as it doesn’t depend on the `thenApply` stage. If, however, you don’t chain the `thenApply` stage, you’re returning the original `completionFuture` instance and canceling this stage causes the cancellation of all dependent stages, causing the `whenComplete` action to be executed immediately.

But when the `thenApply` stage is cancelled, the `completionFuture` still may get completed when the `pollRemoteServer(jobId).equals("COMPLETE")` condition is fulfilled, as that polling doesn’t stop. But we don’t know the relationship of `jobId = schedule(something)` and `pollRemoteServer(jobId)`. If your application state changes in a way that this condition can never be fulfilled after canceling a download, this future will never complete…

---

Regarding your last question, which future is “the one I should hold on to?”, there is no requirement to have a linear chain of futures, in fact, while the convenience methods of `CompletableFuture` make it easy to create such a chain, more than often, it’s the least useful thing to do, as you could just write a block of code, if you have a linear dependency. Your model of chaining two independent stages is right, but cancellation doesn’t work through it, but it wouldn’t work through a linear chain either.

If you want to be able to cancel the source stage, you need a reference to it, but if you want to be able to get the result of a dependent stage, you’ll need a reference to that stage too.

Comment: OP doesn't need the result of `whenComplete`, though. But my understanding is that this stage must be explicitly retained, otherwise it's unreachable and may or may not exist at the time of cancellation.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I guess the original future that you call `whenComplete` on retains the reference to the chained one... Otherwise, it would be seriously screwy.

Comment: @kaqqao It's probably right due to the way one expects this to be implemented, but it's still unspecified behavior and unhealthy to rely on.

Comment: @Holger Please see my edited question. Is this the right way to check for cancellation? I couldn't find a different way and this looks dreadful... It does behave as desired though: canceling the result of `download` cancels the `pollForCompletion`, shutting the executor as well.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik you do not need to keep references to each `CompletableFuture` to have them executed. If you had to, it would break the API of `CompletionStage` which indicates that the task will be executed without such a requirement. Also, it would be a nightmare to use. Anyway, `CompletableFuture` holds hard references internally via its `Completion stack`.

Comment: @DidierL There is no explicit wording to that effect.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik exactly, the wording in the javadoc is “_Returns a new CompletionStage that, when this stage completes normally, is executed […]_”. So it MUST be executed even if you do not keep a reference to it. If it was otherwise, there would be an explicit wording for it.

Comment: @kaqqao: you don’t need to poll `resulting.isCancelled()` as `thrown` will be `CancellationException` then. But actually, you don’t need any check at all. You can simply use `resulting.whenComplete((result, thrown) -> job.cancel(true));` as by the time, the function is executed, either, `resulting` has been canceled or the `job` has been completed, in which case it will ignore the cancellation anyway.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik: every time I `submit` a job to an `ExecutorService` or register a listener to an event source, I assume that it will retain a reference to the object to fulfill the contract. Well, actually, it is indeed not guaranteed that the *object* is still alive, but that doesn’t matter as long as the *associated action* is performed, which is, what this is all about. We want the `BiConsumer`’s `accept` method to be executed; the `CompletableFuture` returned by `whenComplete` is irrelevant…