# Java Futures Pipelining

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, asynchronous, cassandra

I'm trying to optimize my `Future`s management techniques.

Suppose we have this typical processing scenario: I run a query to fetch some records from a database:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycondition;
```

This query returns a lot of rows that I need to process with something like:

```
while (recordset have more results) {
    MyRow row = recordset.getNextRow(); // Get the next row
    processRow(row);                    // Process the row
}
```

Now suppose that all the rows are independent of each other, and the function `processRow` is slow because it performs some hard processing and queries on a C* cluster:

```
void processRow(MyRow row) {
    // Fetch some useful data from the DB
    int metadataid = row.getMetadataID();
    Metadata metadata = getMetadataFromCassandra(metadataid);

    // .... perform more processing on the row .....

    // Store the processing result in the DB
    ProcessingResult result = ....;
    insertProcessingResultIntoCassandra(result);
}
```

A serial approach like this is expected to perform poorly, so a parallel execution is arguable.

With this basic processing structure in mind, here's some transformations I performed on the algorithm to get a major speed upgrade.

---

**STEP 1: parallelize row processing**

This is pretty straightforward. I created an `Executor` that gets the *jobs* done in parallel. Then I wait for all the jobs to finish. The code looks like:

```
ThreadPoolExecutor executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor)Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
int failedJobs = 0;
ArrayList<Future<Boolean>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
while (recordset have more results) {
    final MyRow row = recordset.getNextRow(); // Get the next row

    // Create the async job and send it to the executor
    Callable<Boolean> c = new Callable<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean call() {
                try {
                    processRow(row);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return false; // Job failed
                }
                return true; // Job is OK
            }
    };
    futures.add(executor.submit(c));
}

// All jobs submitted. Wait for the completion.
while (futures.size() > 0) {
    Future<Boolean> future = futures.remove(0);
    Boolean result = false;
    try {
        result = future.get();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    failedJobs += (result ? 0 : 1);
}
```

---

**STEP 2: limit the number of concurrent rows**

So far so good, unless I have a low number of *jobs* this is expected to fail with an out of memory error, because the executor is backed by an unbound queue, and the main loop would submit the jobs all the way. I can solve this problem by controlling the maximum number of concurrent submitted jobs:

```
final const int MAX_JOBS = 1000;
while (recordset have more results) {
    ....
    futures.add(executor.submit(c));
    while (futures.size() >= MAX_JOBS) {
        Future<Boolean> future = futures.remove(0);
        Boolean result = false;
        try {
            result = future.get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        failedJobs += (result ? 0 : 1);
    }
}
```

Simply told, I wait for the first job of the list to be completed if we reached a certain threshold (1000 in this case). This works effectively, and this is a good speedup.

---

**STEP 3: parallelize the single row processing**

This is the step where I'd like to get a bit of help. I expect **1000** jobs will accumulate fast in the queue, due to the slowness of the IO. That is, I expect the JVM to fire **1000** threads to accomodate all the jobs. Now, 1000 threads when you only have an 8-core machine usually slow down everything, and I'm thinking that with a more tweaked parallelism this number could be lowered.

Currently, the `getMetadataFromCassandra` function is a wrapper around `session.executeAsync`, but manages retries:

```
public static ResultSet getMetadataFromCassandra(...) {
    int retries = 0;

    // Loop here
    while (retries < MAX_RETRIES) {
        // Execute the query
        ResultSetFuture future = session.executeAsync(statement);
        try {
            // Try to get the result
            return future.get(1000 * (int)Math.pow(2, retries), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Ooops. An error occurred. Cancel the future and schedule it again
            future.cancel(true);
            if (retries == MAX_RETRIES) {
                e.printStackTrace();

                String stackTrace = Throwables.getStackTraceAsString(e);
                logToFile("Failed to execute query. Stack trace: " + stackTrace);
            }

            retries++;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

As you can see, this is a blocking function because I `.get()` on the `ResultSetFuture`. That is, this call will block each thread waiting for the IO. So I'm getting an async approach, but I feel like I'm wasting a lot of hardware resources.

---

**QUESTION**

In my mind, I should be able to be notified when the `.executeAsync` results are available (or the timeout occurs), "freeing" the thread and allowing the same thread to perform other things.

Simply told, it seems to me that I'd need to transform the *sequential* structure of the `processRow` into a *pipeline*: the query is executed in an async way and, when the results are available, the remaining part of the processing is performed. And of course, I want the main loop to wait for the whole *pipelined* process to finish, not only the first part.

In other words,the main loop submits a job (let's call it `jobJob`) and I get a `Future` (let's call `jobFuture`) that I can `.get()` to wait for its completion. However, `jobJob` fires the "query" sub-job (let's call it `queryJob`), and `queryJob` is submitted async, so I get another `Future` (let's call it `queryFuture`) that should be used to fire the "process" sub-job (let's call `processJob`). At this point, I'm simply nesting `Futures` and blocking deep in the chain before completing the `Future` representing `jobJob`, and that means I'm back to the origin!!!

Before I go the hard route and implement this sort of pipeline as a Finite State Machine, I had a look at:

- `ForkJoinPool` executor class
- `ListenableFuture` from the `Guava` library
- `CompletableFuture` class

None of them seem to satisfy my requirements of pipelining this process, or probably I didn't find a clear explanation on how to perform such apparent simple task. Can anyone simply enlighten me on this topic?

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Not really sure I understood everything, but `CompletableFuture` is staged, so that stages can be pipelined. See my recent question that helped me understand how they're meant to be used, maybe it also helps you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40258146/completablefuturewhencomplete-not-called-if-thenapply-is-used
  Maybe you should go backwards, submit `processJob` first, get `processFuture`, then `processFuture.thenApply(processJob).thenApply(jobJob)` or something like that.

Comment: All of the Cassandra driver's async methis return `ListenableFuture`s. Those support continuations. You don't really need anything else. (Ideally just a general thread pool so as not use the IO threads.)